# JSON.net functions no longer working in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ssis, json.net

I built a very simple SSIS script function to retrieve data from an API and convert the JSON response to XML.  I used json.net deserializexmlnode and it worked perfect in Visual Studio 2008 - unfortunately I was forced to upgrade to 2012 and I cannot for the life of me get the json.net functions to work, I have:

- reloaded the reference with NuGet
- reloaded the reference manually
- verified that I was using the correct version for .net 4.5
- tried the .net 4.0 and 3.5 versions for good measure attempted workarounds
  using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json, but that results in other
  errors

here is the line with the error:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(strResponse, "Root");
```

it worked fine in 2008, but now everytime I get:

```
DTS Script Task: Runtime Error
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Any help you all could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: VtC as a duplicate. I'm assuming you need to register/reregister the assembly in the GAC. `gacutil -if Newtonsoft.dll` Otherwise, we'll need more code to repro your issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help with this - it seems to be working fine now.